# BeautifulSoup parsing numbers over text from HTML

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm learning Python and trying to parse data using BeautifulSoup. I wish it to print the IPv4 rather than the IPv6 address from a whatsmyip website. I can't seem to figure out why it parses the IPv6 over the IPv4 when the first occurrence is the IPv4 address in the html tags. Appreciate any help on this.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.whatsmyip.net")
pagehtml = page.read()
page.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(pagehtml)

data = soup.find_all("input")
for input in data:
    ip = input.get('value')
print ip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because the IPv6 address is the last one found in `<input>` element. You are iterating over all `<input>` elements and as a result your `ip` variable remembers the last one.

Try this:

```
print data[0].get('value')
```

Comment: You are welcome. If you are happy with my answer you'll express it better by voting and accepting it. :)